# VC++ compiler output order

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmd

Suppose we invoke:

```
cl.exe a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp d.cpp
```

Each of the 4 source files contain some errors/warnings.

The order of the console output is often all jumbled up and the ordering changes from different invocations of the same command.

This is presumably due to cl.exe taking advantage of multiple cores and compiling the files concurrently.

However, is there a way that will allow me to view the output in a sensible order such as all errors/warnings from a.cpp followed by b.cpp etc

Comment: cl.exe only does parallel computation if you have /MP set.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the files one by one.

```
cl.exe /c a.cpp
cl.exe /c b.cpp
cl.exe /c c.cpp
cl.exe /c d.cpp
```

and then link them together in a separate command.